# Bind variable 49 not declared when concatenating date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to concat the date with time to convert them into a timestamp, but I'm getting an error.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(22-05-2015) ||" "|| to_char(21:49:00 1600),
       'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS FF9')  FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `to_char` function converts a value from another data type - number, date - to a string. You don't have a date, you have a string, which you have not quoted properly; the colon in the time portion is causing the bind variable error because that isn't quoted either. Double-quotes are used for identifiers, not strings, which are enclosed by single quotes. You don't really need to concatenate two hard-coded strings together anyway.

So you could do:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('22-05-2015 21:49:00 1600', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS FF4')
FROM DUAL;
```

Though it would be more common to use a decimal point rather than a space between the seconds and milliseconds.

Or since you are supplying all the data as fixed values you could use an ISO-format timestamp literal:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-05-22 21:49:00.16' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you so uch alex but i have to convert date into char then again into date

Comment: You haven't shown an actual date (an Oracle DATE type) in your question. If there is one, where is it coming from? And where is the time part coming from?